# How to integrate types defined in an external file in a React Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a `Typescript` based `React Native` project where i want to externalize - and thus reuse - type definitions like `interface`, `enum` etc in a file(or perhaps a few files within a directory).

My understanding is that this should work if i define a `types` or `typings` entry in my `package.json`. This doesn't seem to work as my IDE complains about not finding name when i attempt a simple `Interface` integration. I can of course `import` the required definitions in my files, but i thought that being an 'official' typescript project(using the template provided by `@react-native-community`) these should work out of the box.

My package.json:

```
{ 
  "name": "appname",
  "typings": "./src/typings/index.d.ts",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.22",
    ....
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  ....
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext",                      
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "lib": ["es6"],                           
    "allowJs": true,                          
    "jsx": "react-native",                    
    "noEmit": true,                           
    "incremental": true,                      
    "isolatedModules": true,                  
    "strict": true,                           
    "moduleResolution": "node",               
    "baseUrl": "./",                          
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    
    "esModuleInterop": true                  
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

An example usage for a component:

```
export const ActionButton:React.FC<ActionButtonProps> =(props)=>{
...
}
```

where `ActionButtonProps` reads:

```
export enum EButtonType {
    primary= "PRIMARY", secondary= "SECONDARY", tertiary="TERTIARY"
}

export interface ActionButtonProps {
    title: string
    submitting: boolean
    onPress: ()=>void
    hideLoading?: boolean
    loadingSize?:number | "small" | "large" | undefined
    loadingColor?: string
    type?: keyof typeof EButtonType
}
```

I want to externalize the above in a separate file (defined in the `typings` property in `package.json` or something similar) and not have to import the required type definitions in each file i want to use it.

Currently my IDE complains with `TS error 2304`: 'Cannot find name ActionButtonProps' even though the file i have referenced in the `typings` property in `package.json` has the entries already defined.

I am assuming its just a case of missing some configuration or perhaps changing entries.

I tried the following, none of which works:

- Have a triple-slash reference entry on top of the component file with a path attribute pointing to the file: `/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/index.d.ts" />`
- Have a triple-slash reference entry on top of the component file with a path attribute pointing to a file that sits alongside: `/// <reference path="./ActionButton.d.ts" />`
- Add an `include` property with wildcard values to `tsconfig.json`: `"include": ["src/**/*","./src/typings/**/*"],`
- Add a `typeRoots` property with wildcard and non-wildcard values to `tsconfig.json`: `"typeRoots": ["src/typings/", "src/typings/**/*"],`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. If there is a solution, i have an additional pertinent query as well. Is there a way i could have the `index.d.ts` call separate files that reside in directories inside it? i.e `src > typings > index.d.ts` that calls entries defined in `src > typings > moduleA > index.d.ts` and `src > typings > moduleB > index.d.ts`

**Edit**

my TS version is 3.6.4 and node version is 12.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to include types without importing them is using `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`. From the code you provided it looks like when you tried this you didn't add types from node_modules, which may be why it didn't work.

This config has worked for me in several projects:

```
"typeRoots" : [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./src/typings"
]
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types for more details.

Comment: Since the docs did mention `..by default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation...`, i changed my directory name to `@types` and made the change you had suggested replacing the directory name. I still get the same squiggly line and error. Also attempted removing/adding `"types": "./src/@types/index.ts",` to `package.json` with the same result. Though there is an improvement with the IDE now showing the possible fixes cue that has options to either 'define a new type'(in-page) or 'extract types to a new file'.

Comment: Just for reference, and i have updated the question as well, my TS version is 3.6.4

Comment: ...and additionally the IDE cue also has a fix to 'import the_named_type  from index.d.ts', which is the file in the @types directory. But I am trying to avoid an explicit import, if possible.